# Unable to present accepted conference paper after mentioning it on submitted applications

Tags: publications, graduate-admissions

I'm applying to PhD programs in Computer Science. I recently had a paper of mine accepted into a conference workshop. In my graduate school applications (which I have already submitted), I mentioned this paper, citing it as "To be presented at [Conference/Workshop name]", with a link to the paper. I have it in my CV, and said a few words about it in my Statement of Purpose as well.

However, due to unforeseen circumstances, it's likely that I will not be able to attend the conference to present the paper. Might this be an issue with admissions, and if so, how should I go about notifying them?

EDIT: Workshop papers are included in the proceedings in this conference, but only if the author is able to register for the conference and present the paper.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If this is something like a doctoral symposium in which papers are discussed but not printed in the proceedings, then you should just inform everyone who matters of the situation. It shouldn't be a problem. Acceptance actually means something in a situation like this. And you can always, in this case, submit the paper elsewhere if it doesn't appear or if acceptance is withdrawn by the committee due to not being able to attend.

On the other hand, if the paper will be in the proceedings whether you are there or not, which may be the case in CS, then you don't really need to do anything. You could still inform people, but the acceptance for the conference and publication in the proceedings is all that is really required.

But in general honesty and forthrightness is a plus.

Comment: Accepted workshop papers are published in the proceedings of this conference, but only if the author is able to register for the conference and present the paper (which I am likely not able to). Does that make a difference? My main worry is them cross-referencing the proceedings (if they are published before the decision date) and not finding my paper, and then suspecting me to be dishonest about being accepted into the conference. Do you think this is a possibility to be concerned about?

Comment: Very often your paper is removed from the proceedings if you do not attend the conference that otherwise publishes proceedings. That would be a third case because you have more or less promised that it will be published, but it will not.

Comment: If you have a medical or other compelling reason that you can't attend, I'd first contact the program committee and ask for guidance. If the paper is to be withdrawn, just notify everyone who need to know of the situation.